# Creating a Batch to change a line (find and replace text)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that replaces a line in a text file.

The line is:
**Window Resolution:**

Depending on some settings in my program, this line can look like this:

**Window Resolution: 1**

**Window Resolution: 2**

**Window Resolution: 3**

I need to replace **Window Resolution: (number)** with **Window Resolution: 1** using a batch.

My first guess would be to create something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=configfile.txt
set OutputFile=tempconfigfile.txt
set "_strFind=Window Resolution:"
set "_strInsert=Window Resolution: 1"

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%" (echo %_strInsert%) else (echo %%A)
  )
)

DEL %InputFile%
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%

ENDLOCAL
```

But I can't get this working... Any advice would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%"`: `Window Resolution: x` will never be equal to `Window Resolution:`. Replace your `if` approach with:

```
echo %%A|findstr /bc:"Window Resolution:" >nul &&echo %_strInsert%||echo %%A
```